# Second Lie group cohomology: e-smooth cocycles

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

It is well known that in the category of groups, we have:
\begin{equation*}
Ext(G,A) \cong H^2_{gr}(G,A),
\end{equation*}
where by $H^2_{gr}(G,A)$ I mean the second group cohomology:
\begin{equation*}
H^2_{gr}(G,A):=\{\omega: G \times G \to A| \omega \; \; \text{is a cocycle} \}/\sim.
\end{equation*}
If we now turn to Lie groups, and we define the notion of central extension of a connected Lie group $G$ by a connected abelian Lie group $A$, $H^2_{gr}(G,A)$ does not classify all central extensions in the Lie theoretic sense. My naive approach would be to consider only smooth cocycles and define
\begin{equation*}
    H^2_{s,gr}(G,A):=\{\omega: G \times G \to A| \omega \; \; \text{is a cocycle and it is smooth}\}/ \sim.
\end{equation*}
Intuitively, I would say that $Ext_{Lie}(G,A) \cong H^2_{s,gr}(G,A)$. However, [in this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0393044087900271) it is stated that $H^2_{s,gr}(G,A)$ only classifies those central extensions that admit a global smooth section. I do not see why this would be the case. Furthermore, they claim that the cocycles, which are smooth around the identity
\begin{equation*}
       H^2_{es,gr}(G,A):=\{\omega: G \times G \to A| \omega \; \; \text{is a cocycle, smooth around} \; \; e \in G\}/ \sim.
\end{equation*}
classify all central extensions of $G$ by $A$ in the Lie theoretic sense, i.e. $Ext_{Lie}(G,A) \cong H^2_{es,gr}(G,A)$, this is proposition 3.11 in [the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0393044087900271). They provide a sketch of a proof, which I can not follow. Could someone help me to write down this group isomorphism quite explicitly and to see why it is an isomorphism?

Comment: In the discrete case, a bijection is given by sending a central extension to a cocycle, up to equivalence. the definition of cocycle yes, includes a section. However, now if I want to send a Lie group extension to a suitable cocycle, why do I choose not globally smooth cocycles,but only smooth ones around the identity? i don't understand this

Comment: to see that the map I proposed is not bijective would be equivalent to giving a central extension of a connected Lie group G by a connected abelian Lie group A, which does not admit a global smooth section. how is this possible?

Comment: Oh, I see your point. So the suggestion is to rethink what we really mean by extensions using the following theorem:

1->A->E->G->1 is a Lie group extension <=> E->G is a principal A-bundle.

Could you perhaps refer me to a book, where this is discussed? If this theorem holds, I fully understand all your arguments and everything makes sense.